# Document tree is the same as DOM?

Tags: html, css, dom

Here is the sentence

> The pseudo-class concept is introduced to permit selection based on
>   information that lies outside of the document tree or that cannot be
>   expressed using the other simple selectors.

from http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes

Is "document tree" have the same meaning as DOM or it's something else?

Comment: The document tree is part of the DOM. The DOM contains the _entire_ document object model - for example APIs like timers (setTimeout) and XMLHttpRequest are a part of the DOM but are _not_ a part of the document tree. The document tree is the part that actually represents your well... presented document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

DOM stands for document object model and describes the tree strcuture of elements that form the (HTML) document.

When the CSS spec talks about a document tree it refers to the same thing.

In the sentence you've cited the document says the information, for example whether a link has been visited or not, is not stored in a DOM node.

Take a look at this screenshot of the Firebug inspector showing a part of the DOM of this question and the DOM properties.

[image: Firebug: Document tree excerpt of this question showing the link to the W3C docs and the DOM properties pane]

In CSS you could create this selector and apply styles to a link that has been visited:

```
a:visited {
    ...
}
```

There's no `visited` attribute in the DOM node that Javascript could access too, thus this informaion is *outside the DOM tree*.

Comment: Basically, according to the other answer, 'document tree' is a hypernym for XML/HTML DOM, so the answer can be yes.  But DOM can also be applied to other languages, and those other languages do not have a document tree?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: of course, other languages may have a document tree too, but it depends on the (markup) language. And basically not every datastructure that can be represented as a tree is a "**document** object tree": e.g. program code (Java, Javascript, Python, C, ...) can be represented as a tree structure, but describing it as "_objects_ forming a _document_" is a bit strange - those structures are called AST (abstract syntax tree).

Answer (score 4):

For the purposes of using CSS with HTML, whether you call it a document tree or a DOM tree doesn't make much of a difference. As an author working with HTML and CSS, all you need to know is that the tree is the structure of elements as marked up in the HTML.

The *DOM*, short for *Document Object Model*, is a set of APIs through which elements of an HTML or XML document can be accessed and modified. Strictly speaking, the DOM, in itself, is not *the document tree* (or *a* document tree for that matter), but an interface to said tree (although the tree itself can be implemented *according to* the DOM). See [What is the Document Object Model?](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/introduction.html) in the DOM spec for a lengthy explanation.

Furthermore, a document tree may not *necessarily* be represented or interfaced with by the DOM, since CSS may be used to style things other than HTML or XML DOM trees. The DOM provides just one *implementation* of the concept of a "document tree". This is why the Selectors spec (and related specs) never refer to the document tree as "the DOM" or "the DOM tree", except when specifically referring to the DOM standard.

The definition of a "document tree" according to CSS, then, can be found in the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#doctree):

> **Document tree**
>   The tree of elements encoded in the source document. Each element in this tree has exactly one parent, with the exception of the root element, which has none.

When the source document language is HTML or XML, and the implementation used is the DOM, the resulting document tree is a DOM tree.

Comment: I want to disagree for a few reasons.  Mainly, in direct contradiction to what you're saying: DOM is short for XML DOM, which extends to (afaik), all HTML-like languages that support CSS.  Separately, more a matter of rhettoric: your source seems forced (it's W3, not CSS, and there's nothing in the definition you're citing that limits a document tree to HTML).  W3 also specifies DOM as XML DOM.  *I am not an expert.*

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: Yeah, I knew I was going to have to mention XML directly and not just HTML, so I've fixed that. I'm having trouble understanding your rhetoric, though.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: Um... because CSS is a W3C standard? Why would it be strange? Saying "W3C CSS" on the other hand would be redundant. And CSS can be implemented by anyone for any sort of language - but that doesn't change the fact that CSS itself remains a W3C standard.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: Ah, OK. CSS is indeed a language. However the language is dictated by its specification ("the spec" for short). This specification is a work; it is maintained by its author the W3C CSS Working Group. You can either cite the title of a work or the name of its author (or both). In my case, I choose to cite the work because it's more meaningful to say where or what the quotation is coming from rather than who wrote it.

Comment: The DOM is designed to be used with any programming language. In order to provide a precise, language-independent specification of the DOM interfaces, we have chosen to define the specifications in Object Management Group (OMG) IDL [OMG IDL], as defined in the CORBA 2.3.1 specification [CORBA]. In addition to the OMG IDL specification, we provide language bindings for Java [Java] and ECMAScript [ECMAScript] (an industry-standard scripting language based on JavaScript [JavaScript] and JScript [JScript]). - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/introduction.html